# Ngnix proxy in docker compose with frontend and backend services

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I can't resolve my problem with redirecting traffic to my services in one host.
Here's my current Docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  backend:
    build:
      context: /root/api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.domain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PATH=/api/
      - VIRTUAL_DEST=/api/
  front:
    build:
      context: /root/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.domain.com
      - VIRTUAL_DEST=/
      - VIRTUAL_PATH=/
```

my backend service serve all endpoints on /api/*
and I want to redirect all from app.domain.com/* to frontend service, and all from app.domain.com/api/* to backend service.
But with this configuration, only app.domain.com/ is redirected to frontend, for example app.domain.com/login gives 404 error.
How to fix it?

Comment: The Nginx configuration seems critical to this.  Can you [edit] the question to include that, and any other details that would be necessary for a [mcve]?